# Read text file to 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, transpose

The purpose of the program is to read a 2d array from a file and transpose it. I have the transposing part done. How do I read the file into the array?
The array that I need to work with is 5x5

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class prog464d{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    final int[][] original = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < original[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(original[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n\n matrix transpose:\n");
    // transpose
    if (original.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < original[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < original.length; j++) {
          System.out.print(original[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: File, what file?  Can not see any effort to read a file.

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) <-- Java Tutorials --> [File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like down below. I've heard that not many people use the .split() String method, but I love using it haha. you're gonna have to import `java.io.File`, `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, and `java.util.Scanner`. Also, this is assuming that the text file uses tabs as its delimeter. If the text file is a different dimension, just change `ROWS` and `COLS` to the new dimensions of the new array

```
final int ROWS = 5;
final int COLS = 5;

int[][] nums = new int[ROWS][COLS];
// this is used only in java 7 (not java 6)
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"))) {
    int row = -1; // since we're incrementing row at the start of the loop
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        row++;
        String[] line = input.nextLine().split("\t");
        for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            try {
                nums[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(line[col]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do something here
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you are using Java 6, then the outer try/catch just looks like:

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
    // insert rest of code here
    input.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
String row;
int i=0;
while( (row = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    String[] tokens = row.split(" ");
    int j =0;
    for(String token : tokens) {
        original[i][j++] = Integer.parseInt(token);
    }
}
```

This is assuming your file looks something like:
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 4 5

row.split(" ") will return an array of strings. The for loop converts each one to an int and stores it in original.